# Well-posedness or existence for a Poisson problem in Orlicz spaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, existence-theorems, orlicz-spaces

I know that the problem
\begin{equation}
\Delta_p u = f
\end{equation}
make sense if $f \in L^q$ with $n/p<q<n$ and that is there a existence theory for
$$
u_t -\Delta_p u = f
$$
For a given open and bounded set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $T>0$ we shall denote the parabolic cylinder $U_{T} = U \times (0,T]$. For the inhomogeneity term $f: U_{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we shall consider
$$
f \in L^{q,r}(U_{T}) := L^{r}(0,T, L^{q}(U))
$$
if
$$
2/r+n/q>1.
$$
What are the analogs for these problem if we are working with the problems
$$
u_t -\Delta_{G^p} u = f
$$
with
$$
f \in L^{G^q,r}(U_{T}) := L^{G^q}(0,T, L^{q}(U))$$
$G^q$ and $G^p$ is an N-function.

In other words, how to generalize this p-Laplacian problem for an Orlicz problem?